# Excel: find right value with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

Maybe a simple question but I don't get the right answer. 
I've got two sheets in Excel, one sheet filled with supplier name and order value. Another sheet with suppliername and invoice value including a -10% and +10% range. Now I want to get an overview with the invoices which could be matched on supplier AND the value which could be found within the -10% and 10% range. See below for examples for sheet 1 and sheet 2.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Index and Match functions you can achieve this with a formula.

You need to match the supplier name you want with the list of supplier names on the other sheets, and then index the data you want.

There is a good file here explaining this:

http://www.jpadsolutions.com/HintsAndTips/SampleFiles

Comment: Can you show it to me with an example based on my data? I'm still strugling with it..

Comment: So you presumably have a Sheet 3, for your new overview. And on that sheet you have all the invoice numbers? And next to each invoice number you want formulas that will get you the supplier, value, and the +-10% values from the other two sheets?

Comment: At the end I would like to see those orders which have a match with the sheet invoices. Match is defined as: match on suppliername and ordervalue is between -10% and +10% of the invoicevalue.

Comment: what happens if you have 2 orders for A both with value 10?

Comment: It doesn't matter.. I only need to know or there is a match 'yes' or 'no'.